# Colas de prioridad - Java

Tags: java

Como puedo lograr que se ordenen las distancias de los vuelos según estas tres condiciones:

- Prioridad 1: menor que 500km
- Prioridad 2: entre 500 y 1000km
- Prioridad 3: mayor que 1000km

Usando el comparator, se que retorna `1` para mayores, `0` iguales y `-1` para menores, pero esto es en comparaciones de dos objetos, no logro encontrar la manera para que se ordenen según esos parámetros.

```
 PriorityQueue<aeronaves> pil= new PriorityQueue();
 pil.offer(new aeronaves("avianca",500));
 pil.offer(new aeronaves("linux",400));
 pil.offer(new aeronaves("avianca",500));
 pil.offer(new aeronaves("tame",2000));
 pil.offer(new aeronaves("tame",500));
 pil.offer(new aeronaves("arca",200));
 while(!pil.isEmpty()){
      aeronaves ae= pil.poll();
      System.out.println("aerolina saliento: "+ae.getAerolinea()+"destino "+ae.getDestino());
 }


@Override
public int compareTo(aeronaves t) {
    if(t.getDestino<500){
        return -1;
    }
    if(t.getDestino>=500|| t.getDestino<1000){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: ante igualdad de prioridades, ¿qué criterio se ha de seguir?

Comment: eso no especifica, pero sería optimo que sean de menor a mayor.

Comment: Use en el comparador:

                public int  comparteTo(aeronaves t){
                          int c = t.getDestino();
                           return this.destino - c;
                  }

----------------------
Y funciono, pero no se si este correcto. o debería hacer clases comparadoras por cada condición.

Answer (score -1):

Estás usando mal el método `compareTo`. La forma de implementar la interfaz `Comparable` es la siguiente:

`o1.compareTo(o2)` debe dovolver un valor N que cumple:

- N > 0 si `o1 > o2`
- N = 0 si `o1 == o2`
- N< 0 si `o1 < 02`

Por tanto podrías hacer lo siguiente:

En la clase aeronaves (por cierto, las clases deberían tener siempre la primera letra en mayúscula, es la convención en Java. Y en este caso la llamaría Aeronave, en singular), añade el método getPrioridad:

```
int getPrioridad() {
    if (this.destino<500) return 1;
    if (this.destino<=1000) return 2;
    return 3;
}
```

Y entonces puedes implementar tu compareTo así:

```
int compareTo(Aeronave t) {
    if (t==null) return 1; //un objeto inexistente siempre tendrá menor prioridad
    return this.getPrioridad() - t.getPrioridad();
}
```

Nota: esto no ordena entre Aeronaves de igual prioridad, si lo importante es ordenar por destino podrías simplemente devolver la diferencia entre esos valores.